# Calculating an integral without using the Cauchy Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Stein complex analysis book, and totally stuck up right now.[image]

I can't find a pdf of this book..so I take the photo.
The problem requires me to show the equality 'without' using the Cauchy Integral Formula. I at first thought it would be an easy task...but the calculation seems to be quite nontrivial. Some complicated exponential terms come out on the denominator.....
Could anyone help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you allowed to use Cauchy's integral theorem?

Comment: What exactly are you "allowed" to use then?

Comment: This is the chapter one of Stein's complex analysis book. I am not allowed to use the Cauchy theorem.

Comment: I think I have to solve this problem by just direct calculation of line integral.

Answer (score 2):

Split apart the integrand by partial fractions, and parameterize $\gamma$ as $re^{it}$ with
$0<t<2\pi$.

Comment: Wouldn't you parametrize $\gamma$ as $\color{red}{r}e^{it}$?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I'll edit it.